# server sends raw json and can't be processed by angular

Tags: angularjs, json, express

I'm trying to access the data from server to `$scope.resp` but only raw json is getting displayed on the page.

here is the routes/addr.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var pers = [{add: "abc"},{add: "pqr"}]
        res.json(pers)
   });
  })
```

aj.js:

```
 var app = angular.module('addbook', [])
 app.controller('listcontroller', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('/list').then(function(response) {
    $scope.resp = response
  })
 })
```

There is no error on chrome console. I notice that when $http.get request is commented out it still displays raw json. I saw a similar question where they asked to do do stringify but it is not working.

Comment: try `$scope.resp = response.data`.  The promise object returned by `.then` has other response information, such as `response.status`.  The older, deprecated `.success` callbacks did not include this information.  If this does not help, you should consider updating your question with the HTML that is being used to render `resp`.

Comment: Thanks. I still get only raw json. I notice that even the console.log doesn't work on aj.js file. request reaches the server and renders json and aj.js file doesn't get read.

Comment: `$http.get('/list').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  })`

Comment: How could your view be rendering data if you commented out the `$http.get` which would be retrieving the data? There is still something missing here.  Are you *sure* that you are in an angular view? what is the URL that you are trying to browse to, and, again, what does the HTML template of that URL look like?

Comment: It *sounds* like you aren't really browsing an angular route, but are browsing the server route directly.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense that your router is serving `/`, but your `$http.get` seems to be requesting `/list`.  This is another flag that you aren't really looking at an angular page, especially if you have data.

Comment: Ok trying my best to explain because english is not my first language. I noticed that when I use $http for '/list' and then res.send a static file from server, it displays the right file but I am unable to display data because for that I have to do `res.json` it.  If i do `res.json` it only displays raw json on the page. The reason why you are seeing ' / ' is because it is required already on my app.js and my addr.js file in routes folder only needs ' / '.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99638/discussion-between-claies-and-ann-gilardo).

Comment: I solved this problem. I was sending a request to wrong route. I changed the $http.get route to a different rout and had my server use that route to serve json.

Comment: @ Claies. How can I choose your answer as correct as you helped me solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion in chat, we discovered that the issue was with your Express routes.

Angular is a client framework, which does not perform full page reloads.  The user does not navigate directly to the URL on the server that is serving the data, they navigate to a URL that doesn't exist on the server, which is directed to the index.html file, where Angular is able to perform an AJAX request to retrieve the data from the Server URL and dynamically redraw the page.

If your user navigates to the server route that is serving the RAW JSON, the browser will receive the JSON and display it without any templating, styling, or other page elements.  Therefore, your server URLs and your client URLs need to be different, and your server should use URLs that are exclusively identified as API urls.  many people prepend `/api/` to these URLs to avoid confusion, or secure them so that clients can't request them directly.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a pure Json try to convert like this

```
$scope.resp = JSON.parse(response.data);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your method too. It throws me an error on console with parse. The correct answer was I got my routes wrong. Now it is working.